# Dijkstra Algorithm Running Slowly

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime, hashtable, dijkstra

I made an implementation of Dijkstra's Algorithm and it does work. But when my graph (which is dense) has around 500000 vertices, the algorithm takes too long (more than a minute). It's also taking unusually long to read in the file containing the graph. I'm not sure what's the bottleneck in my program. Below is my code for the algorithm and the hashtable and heap implementations I made with it.

Dijkstra Implementation

```
#include "heap.cpp"
#include <list>
//#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;

//Graph class
//representation of the graph
class Graph
{
public:
    //maps vertex ids to pointers to them
    hashTable* vertices;
    //used to get the unknown vertex with the smallest dv in O(log|V|) time
    //each node in the heap also stores a pointer to the vertex
    heap* unknown;
    //a list of the ids of the vectors
    list<string> nodes;
    Graph()
    {
        //simply creates the hashtable for vertices
        vertices = new hashTable();
    }

    class Vertex;

    //Edge Class
    //representation of the directed edge between two vertices
    //stores the weight of the edge and the vertex the edge points to
    class Edge
    {
    public:
        int weight;
        Vertex* destination;
        Edge(int cost, Vertex* to)
        {
            weight = cost;
            destination = to;
        }
    };

    //Vertex Class
    //stores the id, the shortest known distance from source vertex to it
    //the previous vector in that shortest known path
    //and a list of pointers to outgoing edges from it
    class Vertex
    {
    public:
        string id;
        int dv;
        Vertex* prev;
        list<Edge*> adjacent;
        Vertex(string name, int distance, Vertex* previous, list<Edge*> adjacentList)
        {
            id = name;
            dv = distance;
            previous = prev;
            adjacent = adjacentList;
        }
    };

//insert function
//returns false if the user is attempting to make a loop
//or if the weights entered either aren't positive or are greater than 1 million
//returns true on success
//inserts vertex id and pointer into the hashtable if not already there
//adds a pointer to the newly formed outgoing edge into v1's adjaency list

bool insert(string id1, string id2, int weight)
{
    if(id1.compare(id2) == 0 or weight < 0 or weight > 1000000)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //if the vertex hasn't been seen before
    if (not (vertices -> contains(id1)))
    {
        //create a pointer to the new vertex
        Vertex* vert1 = new Vertex(id1, INT_MAX,  nullptr, list<Edge *>());
        //insert it into the hashtable
        vertices -> insert(id1, vert1);
        //insert its id into nodes
        nodes.push_back(id1);
    }

    if (not (vertices -> contains(id2)))
    {
        Vertex * vert2 = new Vertex(id2, INT_MAX,  nullptr, list<Edge *>());
        vertices -> insert(id2, vert2);
        nodes.push_back(id2);
    }

    //update v1's adjaency list
    (((Vertex*)(vertices -> getPointer(id1))) -> adjacent).push_back(new Edge(weight, ((Vertex*)(vertices -> getPointer(id2)))));


    return true;
}


//finds shortest path from source vertex
//to every vertex in graph
//returns false if vertex given isn't in the graph
//true upon success
bool Dijkstra(Vertex source)
{
    if(not(vertices -> contains(source.id)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //initialize the heap
    unknown = new heap(nodes.size());

    //insert every vertex id into the heap and set their keys to INT_MAX
    for (auto const& i: nodes)
    {
        unknown -> insert(i, INT_MAX, vertices ->getPointer(i));
    }

    //get the pointer for the source node from the hashtable
    Vertex * start = (Vertex *) vertices -> getPointer(source.id);
    //set its dv to 0
    start -> dv = 0;
    //fix the heap
    unknown -> setKey(source.id, 0);

    Vertex* chosen;
    int iterations = 0;
    string id;

    for(int iterations = 0; iterations < nodes.size(); iterations ++)
    {
        //extract from heap unknown vertex with smallest dv
        unknown -> deleteMin(nullptr, nullptr, &chosen);

        //if the min dv in this heap is INT_MAX
        //the rest of the unknown vertices don't have a path to the source vertex
        //so we're done and we can break
        if(chosen -> dv == INT_MAX)
        {
            //continue;
            break;
        }


        //go through its adjaency list and update values
        for (auto const& next : chosen -> adjacent)
        {
            //if chosen_dv + next -> weight < next_dv
            //update dv value on the destination vertex and in the heap
            //make prev of destination vertex chosen
            //else do nothing
            if(chosen -> dv + next -> weight < next -> destination -> dv)
            {
                next -> destination -> dv = chosen -> dv + next -> weight;
                next -> destination -> prev = chosen;
                unknown -> setKey(next -> destination -> id, next -> destination -> dv);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//gets shortest path from given vertex to source
string getPath(Vertex* source)
{
    //if we reached the source vertex
    if(source -> dv == 0)
    {
        //return its id
        return  source -> id + ", ";
    }
    //find the shortest path from the vertex before the given vertex in the path
    return  getPath(source -> prev) + source -> id + ", ";
}

//returns shortest path from source vertex to every vertex in graph
string printSolution()
{
    string output = "";
    Vertex* source;
    string path = "";

    //iterate through list of vertices
    for(auto const& start: nodes)
    {
        //get the pointer to the vertex from the hashtable
        source = (Vertex*)vertices -> getPointer(start);
        output += start + " : ";

        //if the dv is still INT_MAX, there was no path from the source to it
        if(source -> dv == INT_MAX)
        {
            path = "NO PATH\n";
        }
        else
        {
            output += to_string(source -> dv) + " ";
            path = "[" + getPath(source);
            path.erase(path.size() - 2);
            path += "]\n";
        }
        output += path;
    }
    return output.erase(output.size() - 1);
}



};

//prompts user for input
//processes and gives back the results
//of Dijkstra's Algorithm
void Processor()
{
    //variables that will store user input
    string input, output, vertex;

    //prompt user for graph file name
    cout << "Enter name of graph file: ";
    //store it in input
    cin >> input;

    //make graph object
    Graph* chart = new Graph();

    //open input file
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(input);
    string line, arg;

    //vector of arguments to be fed into insert
    vector<string> arguments;
    while(getline(myfile, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        //parse each line by space to get arguments
        while(getline(ss, arg, ' ' ))
        {
            arguments.push_back(arg);
        }
        //insert into the graph
        chart -> insert(arguments[0], arguments[1], stoi(arguments[2]));
        arguments.clear();
    }
    myfile.close();

    while(true)
    {
        //prompt user for start vertex
        cout<< "Enter name of starting vertex: ";
        cin >>  vertex;
        //if the vertex isn't in the graph
        //keep on prompting them until they give a valid one
        if(chart -> vertices -> contains(vertex))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //get the start vertex from the hashtable
    Graph::Vertex source =  *(Graph::Vertex *)(chart -> vertices -> getPointer(vertex));

    //time Dijkstra's algorithm
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    chart -> Dijkstra(source);
    string result = chart -> printSolution();
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);

    cout << "Total time (in seconds) to apply Dijkstra's algorithm: "
         << float(duration.count())/1000<< endl;

    //prompt user for output file
    cout << "Enter name of output file: ";
    cin >> output;

    //open output file
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(output);
    
    //write the results of the algorithm to the file
    outfile << result;
    outfile.close();

}

//just calls on Processor
int main()
{
    Processor();

    return 0;
}
```

Heap

```
#include "heap.h"

//constructor for heap object
//capacity: measure of how much space in heap is left
//size: measure of how many elements (nodes) in heap
//map is a hashTable that allows for constant time access to pointers to nodes from their ids
//creates a hashTable
heap::heap(int length)
{
    data.resize(length + 1);
    capacity = length;
    size = 0;
    map = new hashTable(2*capacity);
}

//constructor for node object
//has an id which is used by the hashTable
//a key which is used to determine its position in the heap
heap::node::node(std::string identi, int pass, void* pvData)
{
    id = identi;
    key = pass;
    pData = pvData;
}

int heap::insert(const std::string &id, int key, void *pv)
{
    //if the heap is almost full, return 1
    if (size == capacity)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //if the id is already in use, return 2
    if(map -> contains(id))
    {
        return 2;
    }
    int index = size + 1;
    node element(id, key, pv);
    data[index] = element;
    map -> insert(id, &data[index]);

    percolateUp(index);
    size += 1;
    return 0;
}

void heap::percolateDown(int posCur)
{
    int index = posCur;
    int child;
    node element = data[index];

    while(index*2 <= size)
    {
        child = index *2;
        if(child != size and data[child + 1].key < (data[child].key))
        {
            child += 1;
        }

        if(data[child].key < element.key)
        {
            data[index] = data[child];
            map -> setPointer(data[index].id, &data[index]);
            index = child;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    data[index] = element;
    map -> setPointer(data[index].id, &data[index]);
}


void heap::percolateUp(int posCur)
{
    int index = posCur;
    node element = data[index];

    while(index > 1 and element.key < data[index /2].key)
    {
        data[index] = data[index / 2];
        map -> setPointer(data[index].id, &data[index]);
        index = index / 2;
    }
    data[index] = element;
    map -> setPointer(data[index].id, &data[index]);
}

int heap::setKey(const std::string &id, int key)
{
    if (not map -> contains(id))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    node *element = ((node*)(map -> getPointer(id)));
    int index = getPos(element);
    data[index].key = key;

    percolateUp(index);

    index = getPos(element);

    percolateDown(index);

    return 0;
}


int heap::remove(const std::string &id, int *pKey, void *ppData)
{
    if(size == 0 or not(map -> contains(id)))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    node * pv = ((node*)(map -> getPointer(id)));
    int index = getPos(pv);
    if(pKey != nullptr)
    {
        *pKey = data[index].key;
    }
    if(ppData != nullptr)
    {
        int *ppData = (int *)data[index].pData;
    }
    setKey(id, -INT_MAX);
    deletion(id);
    return 0;
}

int heap::deleteMin(std::string *pId, int *pKey, void *ppData)
{
    if(size == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(pId != nullptr)
    {
        *pId = data[1].id;
    }
    if(pKey != nullptr)
    {
        *pKey = data[1].key;
    }
    if(ppData != nullptr)
    {
        *(static_cast<void **> (ppData)) = data[1].pData;
    }
    deletion(data[1].id);

    return 0;
}

void heap::deletion(std::string id)
{
    node * pv = ((node*)(map -> getPointer(id)));
    int index = getPos(pv);
    node removed = data[index];
    data[index] = data[size];

    data[size] = removed;
    map -> remove(data[size].id);
    size -= 1;
    percolateDown(index);
    percolateUp(index);

}
```

Hashtable Implementation

```
#include "hash.h"
#include <typeinfo>

//returns a prime number depending on size required for hash table
//supports a size of up to one million
unsigned int hashTable::getPrime(int size)
{
    if (size <= 10000) { return 12373;}
    if (size <= 20000) {return 25867;}
    if (size <= 50000) {return 51479;}
    if (size <= 100000) {return 109211;}
    if (size <= 200000) {return 202717;}
    if (size <= 400000) {return 410299;}
    if (size <= 800000) {return 803549;}
    if (size <= 1600000) {return 2001101;}
    return 3200983;
}

// constructor for hashTable class
//takes initial size input and makes size of table from getPrime
//sets capacity to be initially the size of the hash table
hashTable::hashTable(int size)
{
    int num = getPrime(size);
    length = num;
    data.resize(num);
    capacity = length;
    filled = 0;
}



//hash function
//uses linear probing in the event of a collision
//which is where the function goes from the index
//where the initial hash sent the string to and 
//goes down the table until it either finds a free space
//or it finds the hashitem with that key value
int hashTable::hash(const std::string &key)
{
    int hashVal = 0;
    for(char ch: key)
    {
        hashVal = 37*hashVal + ch;
    }
    int i = 0;

    if (data[hashVal % length].isOccupied)
    {
        while( data[(hashVal + i) % length].isOccupied and 
            (data[(hashVal + i)% length].key).compare(key) != 0)
        {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    return (hashVal + i) % length;
}

//insert function inserts key into position given by hash function
//changes filled and capacity number
//returns 0 on success, 1 when the key has already been inserted
//and 2 if there was a memory allocation error in the rehash function
//if the loading size exceeds 0.5, it rehashes
//this means that at any given time, the hashtable only uses a 1/3 of its actual size
//which is necessary in order to decrease the likelihood of collisions
int hashTable::insert(const std::string &key, void *pv)
{
    //if the key has already been inserted return 1
    //but if the hash item has been deleted, we could insert this key in its place
    //i didn't put this before, this could be what was missing from my code
    int index = hash(key);
    if (((data[index].key).compare(key) == 0) && not(data[index].isDeleted))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    data[index] = hashItem();
    data[index].isOccupied = true;
    data[index].isDeleted = false;
    data[index].key = key;
    data[index].pv = pv;
    filled += 1;
    capacity -= 1;
    if (filled/length > 0.7)
    {
        if (not rehash())
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//multiplies the size of the table by 2
//resizes it based on getPrime of new size
//uses a try catch block on the portion where
//the table is resized
//returns false if memory allocation error occurs
//true if successful
bool hashTable::rehash()
{
    int m = data.size();

    std::vector<hashItem> temp(data);
    //make temporary vector to contain key values
    //temp.resize(m);
    //temp = data;
    //get new size of hashtable
    int size = getPrime(m*2);
    //clear the contents of the hashtable
    data.clear();
    //try to double the size of the hashtable
    try
    {
        data.resize(size);
    }
    //catch any potential memory allocation error
    catch (std::bad_alloc)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //set capacity to size and filled to 0
    capacity = size;
    filled = 0;
    length = size;
    //insert the key into the resized and empty hashtable
    for(int i= 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        //only add in items that weren't deleted
        if(not temp[i].isDeleted && temp[i].isOccupied)
        {
            insert(temp[i].key);
            setPointer(temp[i].key, temp[i].pv);
            filled += 1;
            capacity -= 1;
        }
    }
    //deallocate memory from the temporary vector
    //std::vector<hashItem>().swap(temp);
    return true;
}

//checks if key is in hash table
bool hashTable::contains(const std::string &key)
{
    int index  = hash(key);
    return (data[index]).isOccupied and not((data[index]).isDeleted);
}


//sets pointer of hashItem associated with the key
//to input
int hashTable::setPointer(const std::string &key, void *pv)
{
    if(not contains(key))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    data[hash(key)].pv = pv;
    return 0;
}

//retrieves pointer in hashItem from hashtable
//also writes to a boolean pointer whether or not key is in the table
//returns nullptr if not in the table
void* hashTable::getPointer(const std::string &key, bool *b)
{
    bool con = contains(key);
    //bug
    b = &con;
    if(not con)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    return data[hash(key)].pv;
}



//removes an item from the hashtable
 //via lazy deletion
bool hashTable::remove(const std::string &key)
{
    if(not contains(key))
    {
        return false;
    }
    data[hash(key)].isDeleted = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe more suited for code-review? Did you try to profile the code? Why so much `new` and pointers, looks like Java. Why not `std::priority_queue`?

Comment: All these class methods are getting their parameters by value. Including what seems to be very large lists. Looks like there'll be a huge amount of copying going on. Not to mention using default-construction plus assignment, in constructors, instead of proper member initialization. That's going to add a lot of overhead. I also see a reimplementation of a hashtable. The C++ library knows how to implement a hash table better than any one of us, plus it'll be type-safe, as an extra bonus. In short: there's a lot of inefficiency here, not just one oversight. Needs a complete reimplementation.

Comment: Have you enabled compiler optimisations?

Comment: To add to @SamVarshavchik comment, `std::list` is a double-linked list, it has poor memory locality, and, as a consequence, slow iteration. Use `vector` instead. Reimplementing hashtable is not a bad idea, actually, just don't do it yourself. Using something like [unordered_flat_map](https://github.com/martinus/robin-hood-hashing) can yield 2x speedup over `std::unordered_map`, as it eliminates indirections.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your reply! Could you point out where in the code a list gets passed in? I think that might be it but I can't figure out where it is.

Comment: Well, whichever code constructs a `Vertex` object? As looking at the constructor shows, `Vertex`'s constructor gets its list parameter passed by value, thus requiring the list to be duplicated and copied. And then the constructor initializes its class's member by copying the list ***again***?

Comment: So a dense graph with 500,000 vertices would be approaching *125,000,000,000 edges*?!?  That is a pretty challenging amount of memory to manage.  How long did you think that it would take to do this?